# How to use two cells values as row and column coordinates for referencing another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reference, excel-indirect

I have a range of cells containing numbers, and a range of cells containing letters.

E.g. if I had a value of `d` in one cell, and `7` in another cell, how would I get the value of cell `D7`?

How do I use a combination of one of the letters and one of the numbers to reference another cell and get its value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
=INDIRECT("d"&7)
```

(INDIRECT is volatile.)

Use cell references (not stated) if you want not to hard code.

Comment: But the value of D and 7 are going to change.

D could be A-Z, 7 could be 1-100.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can make a reference to both.

```
=INDIRECT(B1&B2)
```

[image]